# Symfony 4 & encore autorefresh does not work, I always have to reload manually my browser

Tags: css, symfony, webpack-dev-server, symfony4, webpack-encore

From a new Symfony 4 project, when I run this command :

```
./node_modules/.bin/encore dev-server --hot
```

[image]

And then I modify a scss file (change the the body tag background-color by example), the shell react

[image]

But my browser does not automatically refresh ! I always have to reload manually the page for see the latest css change. Where may I do a mystake ?

Thank you !

**=> I tested with different browsers**
**=> If I modify a custom javascript file, the browser autorefresh ! in contrary when I change the scss file**

**=> My assets directory structure :**

[image]

**=> My webpack.config.js content :**

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if you JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('article/main', './assets/js/article/main.js')
    .addStyleEntry('article/style','./assets/css/article/style.scss')
    //.addEntry('page2', './assets/js/page2.js')

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    //.autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

**=> And my automatically generated public/build/manifest.json file :**

[image]

Comment: You might want to check out Browserify

Answer (score 2):

considering the documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/dev-server.html) the Hot Module Replacement (HMR) doesn't work for everything at the moment. It should work for Vue.js but that's all.
For more informations you can check the [documentation for HMR](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/hot-module-replacement/).

TL:DR Your custom js & css assets are not supposed to be hot reloaded in the current state of HMR. You'll have to reload your browser manually. I don't know if you know about the --watch option, but it'll allow you to compile your code every time a file has changed.

Good luck